# I want to define a function with const at the end

Tags: c++, code-injection, objective-c++, cydia

I'm trying to try code injection with MSHook in Objective-C++.

Now I'm trying to hook a function with const at the end of the function and if I put const, I get "pointer to function type cannot have 'const' qualifier" and "non-membe function cannot have 'const' qualifier" errors.

The source code looks like this:

```
int (*Level_getTime)() const;
int _Level_getTime() const {

    return 15000;
}

%ctor {
    MSHookFunction((void*)(0x1007a6db0 + _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(0)), (void*)&_Level_getTime, (void**)&Level_getTime);
}
```

Of course, if I build without const, I won't get an error. However, that would cause the app to crash.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What makes you think that your crash is caused by a lack of `const`? Since const is illegal  in this situation it seems unlikely.

Comment: Is `_Level_getTime` actually a member of something?

Comment: Instead of posting your attempt to fix your crashing code, you should post the crashing code itself.

Comment: A "function with const at the end" has to be a member function, so the problem is probably that you're trying to hook a member with a non-member.

Comment: //The thing that crashes is this
int (Level_getTime)();
int _Level_getTime() { 
return 15000; 
}
 %ctor { MSHookFunction((void)(0x1007a6db0 + _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(0)), (void*)&_Level_getTime, (void**)&Level_getTime); }

Comment: >>molbdnilo  You're probably right.However, when defining it as a member function, I don't know how to put both information because I have to put the address information in MSHookFunction.